# Action item of sherlock action bar hide in device samsung grand

Tags: android

Action item hide in device samsung grand. I have 4  menu items which are displayed same in all device but when i run my application in grand it hides the last item. Menu items order are under
1. Spinner
2. Refresh image Button
3. Add Image Button
4. Search
5. Filter Priority

Menu.xml

```
     <item
            android:id="@+id/Refresh"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
            android:showAsAction="always"

        />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/Search"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:showAsAction="always"

        />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/AddMenu"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:icon="@drawable/add"
            android:showAsAction="always"


        />

        FOR THE SPINNER
 <item
        android:id="@+id/menuSort"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_sort"     

        />  


            <item
            android:id="@+id/overflow"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:actionLayout="@layout/imagebutton" />
      <item
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="Delete All"></item>

SORT LAYOUT FOR THE SPINNER

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
        android:id="@+id/ICSFilter"
        android:popupBackground="#004464"
         android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/my_view_margin1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

I think the problem is about i add spinner to make it  left i have give the margin left. Is that problem  ?? can any body have any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fifth item is probably in the overflow menu, accessed via the ... affordance in the action bar (if your device has no MENU button) or by pressing MENU (if your device has a MENU button).

Comment: No i saw all menu items having extra padding . I have set the paddig to 0 dp and minWidth of the menuItem to 30dp is any solution to remove the padding or have padding same for the all device

Comment: @Bhupendra: When you pressed your device's MENU button, what did you learn?

Comment: Thank u for replay . I have solved the problem. Because of the spinner's margin. Spinner pushing all other menu items, that why last menu item goes hide. i have removed the spinner and change my appliction UI and yes it does not display in option menu